# MSG DATO INCORRECTO

Tags: netbeans

me podéis decir en este código porque al meter un resultado entre 1 y 10 me tira al `else` dato incorrecto?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //variables
        int data, dia, any, cinturo, genere, mes;
        int edat;
        boolean tipusCorrecte;
        boolean pesReal;
        double pes;

        edat = 0;
        genere = 0;
        cinturo = 0;
        pes = 0;
        any = 0;
        mes = 0;
        dia = 0;
        int id = 0;

        System.out.println("PRUEBA");
        System.out.println("INTRODUCE ID:");

        tipusCorrecte = Scan.hasNextInt();
        if (tipusCorrecte) {

            id = Scan.nextInt();
            Scan.nextLine();

            if ((id > 0) && (id < 10)) {

                if ((edat > 4) && (edat < 17)) {
                System.out.println("Introdueix edat:");
                edat = Scan.nextInt();
                Scan.nextLine();
                 } else {
                System.out.println("dato incorrecte");
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("dato incorrecte");

            }


        } else {
            System.out.println("dato incorrecte");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quizá te sale el mensaje del segundo if donde  verificas la variable `edat` y en ese momento es 0 y este valor no es mayor a 4 pero si menor a `17` tendrías un `True  & &  False` y para el operador lógico `&&` tienen que ser los dos `True` por eso salta al `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tienes el Mismo `String`("dato incorrecte") para los todos tus `else`
>   (No es bueno ni un buena practica . debes tener personalizados tus
>   mensajes)

Así que si no haces un `debug` de tu programa tendrás dudas donde ocurre la impresión de tal mensaje. Como en este caso

A Simple vista el mensaje ocurre en tu segundo `if` **anidado** (dentro de otro `if`)

```
if ((edat > 4) && (edat < 17)) {...}
```

Cuando ingresa a este `if` tu variable `edat` tiene el valor de inicialización que es 0 , por lo tanto tendrás

```
 /* False && True*/
if ((0> 4) && (0< 17)) {...}
```

> Por Lógica de los Operadores lógicos esto resultará `False` por lo
>   cual entra a tu `else` e imprime el mensaje.
>   https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_booleanos

Comment: No pero el problema es que introcuzco un dato con scanner para ID

Comment: if ((id > 0) && (id < 10)) {

Comment: si pongo por ejemplo 2, tenemos if (2>0 && 2<10) pero me salta al else

Comment: Imposible que te sale ese if. Con tal entrada. Lo que hace es que pasa al if de la variable edat sin antes haber ingresado valor para esta variable. Lo haces después por eso salta el mensaje como lo explique en mi respuesta

Comment: jajaja, tienes razon, soy un desorden y asi imporsible